# Getting different ModuleNotFound errors for running tests vs running program from command line

Tags: python, import, program-entry-point, nose

I've made a project with the exact tree below.

```
/ project
   / logic
     - app.py
     - utils.py
     - exceptions.py
   / tests
     - tests.py
   - README
   - requirements.txt
```

The code is meant to be run from the command line. `app.py` contains the **main** logic.

Within `app.py`, I import utils like this:
`from utils import validate_args`

So when I run `python app.py`, everything works as expected.

BUT when I run `nosetests`, it fails immediately, citing the import of `utils` in `app.py` as the reason:

```
File ".../project/app.py", line 4, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

This can be fixed by changing the import to `.utils`, but then the command line command fails:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.utils'; '__main__' is not a package
```

I have tried adding `__init__.py` files to the `/project`, `/logic` and `/tests` directories in various combinations to no avail - but honestly I'm just guessing. What am I missing about import logic?

Comment: in test file, add a line before importing logic files,import path                                      sys.append.path(path).

Comment: and to run test from cmd, change your directory to tests

Comment: Thank you @DharmveerSingh, unfortunately neither of these worked for me - I'm getting the same error.

Comment: which file you want to run from cmd

Comment: I fixed this by running the program with the `-m` flag... d'oh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by running the program with the -m flag... d'oh!